# Proving that $(X-1,Y^2-4Y-XY+Y+4)=(X-1,Y-2) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

We consider the ideal $I=(X-1,Y^2-4Y-XY+Y+4)$ of the polynomial ring $k[X,Y]$. I need to prove that $(X-1,Y^2-4Y-XY+Y+4)=(X-1,Y-2) $. Since $Y^2-4Y-XY+Y+4=(Y-2)^2-Y(X-1)$, it is easy to see that $I \subseteq (X-1,Y-2) $, but I can't prove that $(X-1,Y-2) \subseteq I$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is false -- $I$ is not even prime! However, the radical of $I$ is equal to $(X-1, Y-2)$.

Comment: Could you please explain why the radical is equal to $(X-1,Y-2)$ ?

Comment: Well, you should show both containments. First, $(X-1, Y^2 - 4Y - XY + Y + 4)$ is a subset of $(X-1, Y-2)$ (you should figure out why!). Since $(X-1, Y-2)$ is radical (indeed maximal), this implies that $\sqrt{(X-1, Y^2 - 4Y - XY + Y + 4)} \subseteq (X-1, Y-2)$. For the other containment, we need to show that $(X-1, Y-2) \subseteq \sqrt{(X-1, Y^2 - 4Y - XY + Y + 4)}$. How would you do that?

Comment: Oh, I see you already figured out that $I \subseteq (X-1, Y-2)$! My bad. So the only tricky part left is to show that $Y-2 \in \sqrt{I}$. This means showing that $(Y-2)^n \in I$ for some $n \geq 1$. Hint: $n$ can be very small :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I see things clearly now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false since

$$\begin{align}
(x-1,f(x)) &= (x-1,\,f(x)\bmod x-1)\\
           &= (x-1,\,f(1))\\
           &= (x-1,\,y^2-4y+4)\ \ {\rm in\ OP}\\
           &= (x-1,\,(y-2)^2)
\end{align}\qquad$$

but $\,(x\!-\!1,(y\!-\!2)^2)\neq (x\!-\!1,y\!-\!2),\,$ else $\,y\!-\!2 = (x\!-\!1)f + (y\!-\!2)^2g,\,$ so $\,y\!-\!2\mid f,\,$ so cancelling $y\!-\!2$ yields $\,1 = (x\!-\!1)f'+(y\!-\!2)g,\,$ so $\,1 = 0\,$ by eval at $\,x=1,y=2$.